# Raspberry pi 4 steam error /home/meowchinegun/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: raspberry-pi, steam

I flowed a tutorial on how to install steam on raspberry 4. My raspberry is a rpi 4 model B.
I downloaded the steam.deb, then I typed $nano /etc/profile.d/steam.sh and typed in:
`export STEAMOS=1 export STEAM_RUNTIME=1`

I then ran this command    `dpkg -i steam.deb`  From there everything should have worked, but when I clicked on the steam app, nothing happened. From there I when to the terminal and typed in `steam`
it gave me this result:
`steam.sh[4288]: Running Steam on debian 11 64-bit steam.sh[4288]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled by the user setup.sh[4350]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date! steam.sh[4288]: Can't find 'steam-runtime-check-requirements', continuing anyway /home/meowchinegun/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 792:       /home/meowchinegun/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: cannot execute binary file: Exec format     error`

From here I was blank, with no ideas to further continue I stopped, because last time I winged it I broke it.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Here is my    `uname`  if it helps:     `Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

As you can see I'm new to raspberry pi, but not as much with Linux herself

Thats about it

`your text`